# How do I find the current quarter in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services

How would I find the Current Quarter in SSRS? I am trying to set a default value for a parameter to the current quarter. I tried:

```
=QUARTER(NOW)
```

But it returned the following error:

> The Value expression for the report parameter ‘pquarter’ contains an
>   error: [BC30451] 'QUARTER' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due
>   to its protection level.

As of the writing of this post 6/20/2018 I am trying to return `2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the following function:

```
=DatePart("q",NOW())
```

It seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

In SSRS:

```
DatePart(DateInterval.Quarter,Fields!date_var.Value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Quater is a date related and this should work.

```
select DATEPART(Q,GETDATE())
```

Comment: Sorry, It didn't work. I am assuming `SELECT DATEPART(Q,GETDATE())` is a MS SQL Server function. I need something for ssrs.

Comment: I would generally put that into my SQL, but 
    =DatePart("Q",Now()) also seems to work